# Sage CRM - How to open a screen in a popup window a in custom ASP page?

Tags: sage-crm

Kind of the same way when you click in a Search menu of a Avanced Search field

[image]

In the imagen above, the "Buscar" button opens the ´AddressSearchBox´ screen in a popup, i want the same behaivoir but applied to the ´CustomCommunicationDetailBox´ screen when clicking a button in my custom ASP page

I see in the button that it is a lot a Javascript, but do i have to make the onlick button all by hand?

Comment: Are you looking for the same functionality in the popup, or do you just want a popup for your own content?

Comment: In my .asp page being able to call the `CustomCommunicationDetailBox` screen in a popup with filled data (Passing an Comm_Id etc etc) and be able to save it etc etc. I managed to do so using this `var stringURL = crm.url("componet/tabs/Company/Cal/popupscreeens.asp")+"&PopupWin=Y&currCommunication="+CommunicationId;
    window.open(stringURL, 'newwindow', 'toolbar=0 , scrollbars=0, location=0, statusbar=0, menubar=0 , resizable=0, width=800, height=400, left = 340, top = 200')`